# jquery click handler for radio button doesnt work properly

Tags: jquery

if i try to click from top to bottom the radio buttons work nice, but once this cycle is complete they don't get affected.

I'm using the on click on the outer div and then selecting the inner elements via find.

I've provided the code below.

I've updated the code below.  The radio buttons works, but I want the link to be clicked automatically ( it shoudld expand when we click the green panel-heading  class element.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Plan Selection</title>

    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">



    <style>
    @font-face {
        font-family: myFirstFont;
        src: url(styles/2BF294_D_0.woff);
    }

    .heading {
        font-family: MorebiRounded-Regular;
        font-size: 30px;
    }
    .green-bk{
        background-color: #06a94e !important;
    }
    .container {
        margin-top: 40px;
    }

    .plan-info {
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 16px;
        display: inline;
        float: right;
    }
    .continue{
      margin-top: 30px; 
      width:100%;
      color: white; 
      background-color: #06a94e;
      border: 0;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      border-radius: 23px;
      font-family: MorebiRounded-Regular;
      height: 40px;
      font-size: 18px; 
    }
    .continue:hover  
    {
        color: #fff;
        background-image:none;
        background-color:#06a94e;
    }

    .continue:active  
    {
        color: #fff;
        background-image:none;
        background-color:#06a94e;
    }


    .hidd-td{
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    .grey-panel{
        background-color: #ccc;   
    }
     .green-panel{
        background-color: #06A94E;
    }
    .first-td{
        border-top: none !important; 
    }
    .mori{
        font-family: MorebiRounded-Regular;
    }


    .subsection{
        font-family: MorebiRounded-Regular;
        font-size: 16px;
        text-align: center;
        color: white; 
    } 

    .black-subsection{
               font-family: MorebiRounded-Regular;
        font-size: 16px;
        text-align: center;
        /*color: white;  */
    }

.grey-wrapper{
    /*background-color: red;*/
    height:auto;
    margin-bottom: 50px;

}

.push-radio{
    margin-right: 10px !important;
}


/*mobile classes*/


    .mo-heading {
        font-family: MorebiRounded-Regular;
        font-size: 30px;
    }



    .plan-info {
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 16px;
        display: inline;
        float: right;
    }


    .mo-continue{
        color: white;
        width:100%;
        background-color: grey;
        padding:13px; 
        /*font-family: MorebiRounded-Regular;*/
        font-size: 22px;         
    }
    .mo-continue:hover  
    {
        color: white;
        background-image:none;
        background-color: grey;
    }

    .mo-continue:visited  
    {
        color: white;
        background-image:none;
        background-color: grey;
    }  
    .mo-continue:active  
    {
        color: white;
        background-image:none;
        background-color: grey;
    }    

    .mo-push-radio{
        /*margin-right: 1px !important;*/

    }










#DIV_1 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    height: 43px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 1583px;
    perspective-origin: 791.5px 21.5px;
    transform-origin: 791.5px 21.5px;
    border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
    font: normal normal normal normal 17px/normal MorebiRounded-Regular, Arial;
    outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
    padding: 10px 0px;
}/*#DIV_1*/

#SPAN_2 {
    background-position: 0px 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(6, 169, 78);
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    height: 21px;
    left: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 10px;
    width: 60.734375px;
    z-index: 1010;
    align-self: stretch;
    perspective-origin: 30.359375px 10.5px;
    transform-origin: 30.359375px 10.5px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url(https://arlodev.netgear.com/img2/title_back_1.png) no-repeat scroll 0px 50% / auto padding-box border-box;
    border: 0px none rgb(6, 169, 78);
    font: normal normal normal normal 17px/normal MorebiRounded-Regular, Arial;
    outline: rgb(6, 169, 78) none 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
}/*#SPAN_2*/

#SPAN_3 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    text-align: center;
    border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
    font: normal normal bold normal 18px/normal MorebiRounded-Regular, Arial;
    outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
    top:-5px;
}/*#SPAN_3*/




.setup-progress {
    height: 8px;
    background-color: #06a94e;
}

.setup-wrap {
    top: 60px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
}

.change-subs{
    margin-top:10px;
    font-family: MorebiRounded-Regular; 
}

.dark-green{
    background-color: green; 
}

.dark-grey{
    background-color: grey !important; 
}


    </style>

</head>

<body>






<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
 <h3 class="change-subs text-center"> Change Subscription</h3>
</div>
</div>



<div id="DIV_1">
    <span id="SPAN_2">BACK
    </span> 

<!--     <span id="SPAN_3"> 
    <h3 class="change-subs"> 2Change Subscription</h3>
    </span>
 -->
</div>





<!-- mobile starts  -->


  <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">

                <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading green-bk">
                            <h4 class="panel-title mo-heading">

<input class="mo-push-radio" type="radio" name="plan-mobile">                      
                            <a class="mo-planlink"  data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
                            ELITE</a>
                            <div class="plan-info">14.99/Mo | 149.99/Yr </div>
                        </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <table class="table">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            60 Days of Cloud Recording
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            Up to 15 Cameras
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            Unlimited Support
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            Available Add-Ons: 
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading green-bk">
                            <h4 class="panel-title mo-heading">
<input class="mo-push-radio" type="radio" name="plan-mobile">                                                  
                            <a class="mo-planlink" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">PREMIER</a>
                            <div class="plan-info">14.99/Mo | 149.99/Yr </div>         
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <table class="table">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            60 Days of Cloud Recording
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            Up to 15 Cameras
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            Unlimited Support
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            $14 99 / Mo
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading green-bk">
                            <h4 class="panel-title mo-heading">
<input class="mo-push-radio" type="radio" name="plan-mobile">                                                  
                            <a class="mo-planlink" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">BASIC</a>
                          <div class="plan-info">FREE </div>                              
                        </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <table class="table">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            60 Days of Cloud Recording
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            Up to 15 Cameras
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            Unlimited Support
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            $14 99 / Mo
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn mo-continue"> CONTINUE</button>
            </div>

        </div>

</div>

<!-- mobile ends -->

<script>
$(document).ready(function  () {

// mobile

$('.mo-planlink').on( "click", function() {
  console.log( ' plan link clicked ', this );

    var nearestRadio = $(this).parent().find('input'); 

    console.log(' nearest Radio = ', nearestRadio);
    nearestRadio.attr('checked', 'checked');

}); 




$('.mo-push-radio').on( "click", function() {
  console.log( ' plan link clicked ', this );

    nearestRadio = $(this).next().click(); 
    console.log(' nearest Radio = ', nearestRadio);
    nearestRadio.attr('checked', 'checked');

    // nearestRadio.parents().eq(2).addClass('dark-grey');

    var near =   nearestRadio.parents().eq(2).children(); 
  console.log(' near ---> = ', near );

    // near.addClass('dark-grey');




    if( nearestRadio.is(':checked') ){
      nearestRadio.attr('checked', false);
}else{
      nearestRadio.attr('checked', true);
}




}); 



$('.panel-heading').on( "click", function(e) {
    var self =  this; 


    // grab the nearest list and click it. 


    $('.panel-heading').removeClass('dark-grey'); 

    $(this).addClass('dark-grey'); 



var $radios = $('input[type="radio"][name="plan-mobile"]')
    console.log('$radios', $radios);

    $radios.prop("checked", false);

    current_el = $(this).find( "input" ); 
    console.log("current_el =", current_el);
        current_el.prop("checked", true);







var $links = $('a'); 

    console.log('$$links', $links);


    current_a = $(this).find( "a" ); 
    console.log("current_a =", current_a);

    // current_a.click(); 
    // e.preventDefault();

}); 




// desktop

$('.push-radio').on( "click", function() {
  console.log( ' desk - plan link clicked ', this );
    var  nearestSquare = $(this);
    $('.push-radio').parents().removeClass( 'dark-green' );
    nearestSquare.parents().eq(5).addClass( 'dark-green' );


}); 









})

</script>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

your code works ,

```
 nearestRadio.attr('checked', 'checked');
```

you are always setting it to checked after click

did you mean something like:

```
if( nearestRadio.is(':checked') ){
      nearestRadio.prop('checked', false);
      alert('this radio already checked');
}else{
      nearestRadio.prop('checked', true);
      alert('this radio is not checked');
}
```

Comment: @JP. - edited , can you try that and see what happens with the alerts , see if they are responding properly

Comment: @JP. also - I had a typo , I had .attr()  you need .prop()  , try that change as well

Comment: I updated the code , you only want one click handler on the parent of the input.  delete the other click handler.  Also , I'm almost positive that it is invalid HTML to have <h4> with and <input> and <a> as children ,  maybe you want to use a div and style accordingly??